# How to enforce IPv6 source address selection with addrlabel at startup?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a system with a primary IP address of `2001:DB8:1::1/64`. This IP is achieved via stateless auto config and is static for our purposes.

This system has a routed IP block of `2001:DB8:2::/64`.

I would like to ensure that by default, all IPv6 traffic originating from the system uses `2001:DB8:1::1`. (Applications could override this with a specific source binding.)

The best way to do this appears to be, from my research, to run

```
ip addrlabel add prefix 2001:DB8:1::1/128 label 1 
ip addrlabel add prefix 2001:DB8:2::/64 label 99
```

What would be a proper Ubuntu way to have this run at startup?

---

Thanks to [Anders input](https://askubuntu.com/a/304874/164819) i was able to do this by adding the following lines, in /etc/network/interfaces

```
up /sbin/ip addrlabel add prefix 2001:DB8:1::1/128 label 1 
up /sbin/ip addrlabel add prefix 2001:DB8:2::/64 label 99 
...
down /sbin/ip addrlabel del prefix 2001:DB8:1::1/128 label 1 
down /sbin/ip addrlabel del prefix 2001:DB8:2::/64 label 99
```

This works great, and also covers clean-up if the interface is brought down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to /etc/network/interfaces as a post-up to the interface.