# IPv6 source address selection with addrlabel (or similar) with netplan (or similar)

Tags: networking, netplan, ipv6

I have using something similar to [How to enforce IPv6 source address selection with addrlabel at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304643/how-to-enforce-ipv6-source-address-selection-with-addrlabel-at-startup) to configure IPv6 address selection in Ubuntu 16.04.

Now I am deploying Ubuntu 18.04 and the new network configuration tool is "netplan".

This machine has a handful of IPv6 addresses and I want to be able to configure the source address as described in RFC 3484. That is, several IPv6 source addresses are valid for a given destination, but I want to be able to choose what source IPv6 address is used  depending of the destination.

I have tried "routes" and "routing-policy", with no effect. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

I have found some examples por policy routing for IPv4, but all of them use "via" with an static address and I want to use automatic IPv6 router discovery so, technically, I don't know what my router address is, and it could change anytime.

I have tried something like this, with no success:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses:
        - 2001:XXXX:XXXX::1/48
      routing-policy:
        - to: "::/0"
          from: "2001:XXXX:XXXX::1/48"
          priority: 0
```

**EDIT:** My current netplan configuration is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses:
        - 2001:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:1/48
```

Comment: I get most of my configuration via DHCP4/DHCP6. I have a IPv6/48, so I manually added an explicit IPv6 address in that range, and I want that IP to be "source address selected" when initiating outgoing connections. I modified my post with the current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything with routes you need to configure your network device properly.
It should look something like this:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens32:
            addresses:
            - xx.99.99.99/29
            - xxxx:9999:9999::99/64
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            gateway4: xx.99.99.1
            gateway6: xxxx:9999:9999::1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 2001:4860:4860::8888
                search:
                - example.com
```

Comment: I get most of my configuration via DHCP4/DHCP6. I have a IPv6/48, so I manually added an explicit IPv6 address in that range, and I want that IP to be "source address selected" when initiating outgoing connections. I modified my post with the current configuration.